# Find the Source/Bin Folder of Cassandra Which Installed by HomeBrew

Tags: cassandra, homebrew, cql, bin

I am having difficulty to find the source of the Cassandra installed on Mac, which the Cassandra was installed using HomeBrew.

We were asked to use the cql files to populating tables, and I checked couple times that the physical cql file is stored in the listed location. However, I would receive the following error message says the file or directory cannot be found. Could anyone advise please? Thanks!

```
cqlsh:stockwatcher> source '/Users/UserName/Downloads/insertusers.cql';
Could not open '/Users/UserName/Downloads/insertusers.cql': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/UserName/Downloads/insertusers.cql'
```

Comment: try `which cassandra` command, it will probably give you the installed location on your machine

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mac user but did you try `whereis cassandra`? If not, `find / -name cassandra`. If that does not work either, try to look for currently running java apps then look at the how the java executable was invoked; which has details like what libraries are included etc from which we can decipher the path.

But the error message looks more like permissions issue.

Comment: Works on Linux.